# Copy rows from one table to another with the same structure

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to copy rows from `Variables` to `VariablesTest` in SQL Server. The two have the same columns, data types, etc. Reading through the answers below, I'd imagine this to be the way to go

```
set IDENTITY_INSERT VariablesTest ON
insert VariablesTest Select * from Variables
set IDENTITY_INSERT VariablesTest OFF
```

but SQL Server Management Studio throws an error:

```
An explicit value for the identity column in table 'VariablesTest' can only be specified when a column list is used and IDENTITY_INSERT is ON.
```

Sigh...

Comment: The answer is in your error message...  `when a column list is used`.

Answer (score 1):

*"can only be specified when a column list is used"*

The error message is telling you to use a column list:

```
set IDENTITY_INSERT VariablesTest ON
insert VariablesTest(column1,column2,etc) Select column1,column2,etc from Variables
set IDENTITY_INSERT VariablesTest OFF
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know that the columns are the same in both tables you still need to list them for the INSERT portion but the SELECT portion can use an asterisk...

```
set IDENTITY_INSERT VariablesTest ON

INSERT VariablesTest (col1, col2, col3, col4,...) SELECT * FROM Variables

set IDENTITY_INSERT VariablesTest OFF
```

...this isn't stable code and if a column is added to both tables or just one it will break.  So even though this is possible, listing both sets of columns separately is the preferred method.  Using tools such as Red Gate's SQL Prompt can allow you to auto-expand your asterisks into comma delimited lists of columns, so that is also an option and one that I use frequently to save typing and mistakes.